# Why does my code become unable to use external variables at random?

Tags: javascript, html, scope

So, I'm writing a game in HTML Canvas with JavaScript. There's plenty of different JS files for organization sake but, at times, when I declare a new variable, many (if not all) other variables become unaccessible in other files. Why does this happen? I'll give an example so you can understand better. Let's assume I define this variable in file1.js:

```
var randomVariable;
```

Then, here in file2.js I try to use it:

```
randomVariable = 5;
if(randomVariable == 6){
    <some code idk>
}
```

This works, however, sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes the console tells me "randomVariable" is undefined in file2.js. It's inconsistent, I can't pinpoint what seems to cause it. I have a personal library which contains some useful functions, and I use those functions all over the code, but at times, every single of the calls breaks saying its undefined. I can't wrap my head around the issue. Before anyone asks, here is how the .html file is defined:

```
<html>

<canvas id="gameCanvas" width=800
height=600></canvas>

<script src="js/HUD.js"></script>
<script src="js/classes.js"></script>
<script src="js/movement.js"></script>
<script src="js/gameplay.js"></script>
<script src="js/graphics.js"></script>
<script src="js/input.js"></script>
<script src="js/audio.js"></script>
<script src="js/Main.js"></script>

</html>
```

That's the entirety of the html code. I've been told the order at which these files are called does matter. However, sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes I can call functions and variables from "classes" that are defined in "audio". Other times, it breaks. I seriusly need help with this beucase it's making coding impossible.

Comment: The code is being loaded and run at different times/speeds. Sounds like race conditions.

Comment: Have you tried to use modules (ES6 feature), that way you can import and export your variables more easily. More info: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/es6/es6_modules.htm

Answer (score 0):

Add this to every file:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    //Your code here
});
```

This will make sure your code only executes when the windows has loaded. Thus only when all your files are loaded properly.

Comment: So, I put all of the js code inside that function? For every file?

Comment: Yes exactly. Your code will only be executed when you all files are loaded. Also, your files will be loaded from the top down, so be sure to have all variables in the top most files or atleast in the file above the one you want to use the variables in.

Comment: Yeah... it didn't work. Now nothing loads, at all. Will have to remove it. It was a fair shot tho.

Comment: Try adding a body tag to your html like this <body></body> . Then before the </body> paste your Javascript files.